# Why drawables I use in my Android app have wrong aspect ratio when used as buttons background

Tags: android, svg, layout, drawable, aspect-ratio

I put some icons into my Android app layout.

They have been imported by means of the "new vector asset" command, from svg files of the material design Google collection here: https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline

This is the resource xml:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">
 <path
  android:fillColor="#FF000000"
  android:pathData="M13,7h-2v4L7,11v2h4v4h2v-4h4v-2h-4L13,7zM12,2C6.49,2 2,6.49 2,12s4.49,10 10,10 10,-4.49 10,-10S17.51,2 12,2zM12,20c-4.41,0 -8,-3.59 -8,-8s3.59,-8 8,-8 8,3.59 8,8 -3.59,8 -8,8z"/>
</vector>
```

They are used as backgrounds for buttons:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/duplicate_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/duplicate_icon"
        />
```

But the result is not good, because I get something like this:
[image]

A square is expected, while I get a rectangle instead. The svg files have correct proportions when displayed in other applications.

Three buttons are in such a linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```

and there is a container for that:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:border="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ItemDetailFragment">
```

with some other things inside.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You can use 9patch images and it will work properly on any width. It's easy to create them from Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `wrap_content` for your Button width and height will not help you because you are setting your image as background, it is not an actual content of the button. You need to specify fixed dimensions for your button. Depending on your design, I would suggest you to have a look at `ImageButton` or just simply use `ImageView` like this:

```
<!-- ?attr/selectableItemBackground is for button effects -->
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" 
    android:src="@drawable/duplicate_icon" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "wrap_content" does not default to your desired 24dp because the drawable is not actually the content of your button, but only its background. You could set the size of your button explicitly to 24dp, such as the following:

Layout:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/duplicate_button"
android:layout_width="@dimen/my_button_size"
android:layout_height="@dimen/my_button_size"
android:background="@drawable/duplicate_icon"
/>
```

Drawable:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="@dimen/my_button_size"
android:height="@dimen/my_button_size"
android:viewportWidth="@dimen/my_button_size"
android:viewportHeight="@dimen/my_button_size">
```

res/values/dimen.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="my_button_size">24dp</dimen>
</resources>
```